# Using $pull in MongoDB to Update a Document's Inner Array

Tags: database, mongodb, syntax

I have the following object in my database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aee9a0cda447c1ca8bf415d"), "id" : 4, 
  "categoryName" : "Website", "contestName" : "Free programming books", 
  "description" : "\nA list of free online programming books, categorized by languages/topics\n    ", 
  "nameIds" : [ ObjectId("5b0131d66e3a1c705eb93913"), 
   ObjectId("5b0cf2ffe7405204c6e88e5e"), ObjectId("5b0cf712a891af0506382c29") ] }
```

and would like to remove the last element in my "nameIds" array. Right now I'm trying to use

```
db.contests.update({_id: ObjectId("5aee9a0cda447c1ca8bf415d")}, { $pull: { nameIds: "5b0cf712a891af0506382c29" }})
```

but haven't got it to work yet.

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Is there a reason why $pull isn't working in this format? It finds the element but doesn't alter the array in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the objectId to find inside ObjectId() like:

```
ObjectId("5b0cf712a891af0506382c29")
```

The following query works and pulls the respective item from nameIds array:

```
db.contests.update({_id: ObjectId("5aee9a0cda447c1ca8bf415d")}, { 
$pull: { nameIds: ObjectId("5b0cf712a891af0506382c29") }})
```

The update in document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aee9a0cda447c1ca8bf415d"),
    "id" : 4,
    "categoryName" : "Website",
    "contestName" : "Free programming books",
    "description" : "\nA list of free online programming books, categorized by languages/topics\n    ",
    "nameIds" : [
        ObjectId("5b0131d66e3a1c705eb93913"),
        ObjectId("5b0cf2ffe7405204c6e88e5e")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The values in your array are `ObjectId`s. In your update operation, you specify a String literal as the value to remove. This doesn't match the actual value. Use

```
db.contests.update({_id: ObjectId("5aee9a0cda447c1ca8bf415d")}, { $pull: { nameIds: ObjectId("5b0cf712a891af0506382c29") }})
```

instead.